# Using broadcasting with sparse scipy matrices

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, sparse-matrix

I have a `numpy` array `Z` with shape `(k,N)` and a second array  `X` with shape  `(N,n)`.

Using `numpy` broadcasting, I can easily obtain a new array `H` with shape `(n,k,N)` whose slices are the array `Z` whose rows have been multiplied by the columns of `X`:

```
H = Z.reshape((1, k, N)) * X.T.reshape((n, 1, N))
```

This works fine and is surprisingly fast.
Now, `X` is extremely sparse, and I want to further speed up this operation using sparse matrix operations.

However if I perform the following operations:

```
import scipy.sparse as sprs
spX = sprs.csr_matrix(X)
H = (Z.reshape((1,k,N))*spX.T.reshape((n,1,N))).dot(Z.T)
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\base.py", line 126, in reshape
    self.__class__.__name__)
NotImplementedError: Reshaping not implemented for csc_matrix.
```

Is there a way to use broadcasting with sparse `scipy` matrices?

Comment: Besides the 2d limit, sparse math only works with other sparse matrices.  When working with dense arrays, sparse matrices are converted to dense ones.  Play around with `spX` to see what happens with various math operations.

Answer (score 1):

Scipy sparse matrices are limited to 2D shapes. But you can use Numpy in a "sparse" way:

```
H = np.zeros((n,k,N), np.result_type(Z, X))
I, J = np.nonzero(X)
Z_ = np.broadcast_to(Z, H.shape)
H[J,:,I] = Z_[J,:,I] * X[I,J,None]
```

Unfortunately the result `H` is still a dense array.

N.b. indexing with `None` is a handy way to add a unit-length dimension at the desired axis. The order of the result when combining advanced indexing with slicing is [explained in the docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#combining-advanced-and-basic-indexing).